# Set line-terminator string in NSDocument?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, newline, nstextview

(This question has been rewritten from an issue with `NSTextView` following some further research)

UPDATE: You can download a very basic project that displays the issue here:

http://w3style.co.uk/~d11wtq/DocumentApp.tar.gz

(Do a `grep -c "\r" file.txt` on the file you save to get a line count where `\r` occurs... repeat for `\n`).

I've realised all files created by `NSDocument` have `\r` is line endings, not the standard `\n`, even though the `NSData` my document subclass returns does not contain `\r`, it only contains `\n`.  Is there a way to configure this?

I thought Macs used UNIX line endings these days, so it seems weird that AppKit is still using the antiquated Mac endings.  Weirder is that `NSDocument` asks for `NSData`, then rather unkindly corrupts that `NSData` by transforming the line endings.

The switch to `\r` is happening *after* producing `NSData`, so `NSDocument` itself is doing some replacements on the bytes:

```
 const char *bytes = [data bytes];
 int i, len;
 for (i = 0, len = [data length]; i < len; ++i) {
  NSLog(@"byte %d = %02x", i, bytes[i]);
 }
```

Outputs (note 0a is the hex value of `\n`):

```
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.076
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 0 = 66
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.076
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 1 = 6f
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.076
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 2 = 6f
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.077
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 3 = 0a
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.077
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 4 = 62
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.077
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 5 = 61
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.077
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 6 = 72
> 2010-12-17 12:45:59.077
> MojiBaker[74929:a0f] byte 7 = 0a
```

If `NSDocument` is going to ask for `NSData` then it should respect that and not modify it.

Here's the full code from the method: `-dataOfType:error:` method in my document:

```
    -(NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
 NSString *string = [textView string];

 // DEBUG CODE...
 NSArray *unixLines = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
 NSArray *windowsLines = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
 NSArray *macLines = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];

 NSLog(@"TextView has %d LF, %d CRLF, %d CR", [unixLines count] - 1, [windowsLines count] - 1, [macLines count] - 1);

 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
          length:[string lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 const char *bytes = [data bytes];
 int i, len;
 for (i = 0, len = [data length]; i < len; ++i) {
  NSLog(@"byte %d = %02x", i, bytes[i]);
 }

 if (data != nil) {
  [textView breakUndoCoalescing];
 }

 return data;
}
```

Comment: You posted the code you used to examine the data but you haven't posted the code responsible for producing/reading the data. Are you saying this happens entirely with the stock template? I have doubts.

Comment: Just as a followup, I suggest creating a basic test project that does the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's not a stock template, no.  I had started with a Window-Based project and early on realised I'd be better with a Document-based project.  It does just blindly take the (unmodified) string from a NSTextView, turn that string into UTF8 bytes, then return that as NSData though.  All of the debugging lines show exactly what I expect to happen.

Comment: I'll create a little project a post a link.

Comment: Sample Xcode project posted in question.

Comment: I compiled your project, ran it, saved a document, and the resulting text file had only LFs in it, no CRs.  `hexdump -C` is your friend.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the noise.  I'm about to fire my boss who has had me running around on this telling me that this grep command proves I'm generating `\r` instead of `n`.  Hmmf.  You're right, hexdump shows the correct thing.  How embarrassing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDocument doesn’t care about line termination; it’s a semi-abstract class, designed to be subclassed.  By itself it imposes nothing on a file format.

It’s the particular implementation of an NSDocument subclass - one that happens to read and write plain text - that will care about line termination characters.

Comment: Please see my update to the question, which includes a real Xcode project that shows the problem.

Comment: Apologies... the grep command my boss has been running when asking me to fix this bug was wrong... Well, this has been a fun day :P